# How to append "Input Tags" into the DOM in Runtime Dynamically using Selenium JavascriptExecutor?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, executor

I need to append the following element to the DOM in run time(dynamically)..

```
    <input type="text" name="imagesToAdd" value="3566">
```

I tried doing it by using Selenium JavascriptExecutor; But it gives an error saying "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: document.getElementById(...).append is not a function"

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript("document.getElementById('post-ad_title').append('<input type=\"text\" name=\"imagesToAdd\"value=\"3566\">')");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) with setting the required attributes;

```
String script = "var p = document.createElement('input');var ele = document.getElementById('post-ad_title');p.setAttribute('type','text');p.setAttribute('name','imageToAdd');p.setAttribute('value','3566'); ele.appendChild(p);";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script);
```

Comment: this worked fine but added the button at the end of the page, how can i inject an <img> attribute into a specific div ?

Comment: this is my div :  <div class="note-editable" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" style="height: 200px;">